# Clearing graph before replotting matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, user-interaction

I have a little app that allows me to change an input value with a tKinter scale widget and see how a graph reacts to different changes in inputs. Every time I move the scale, it's bound to an event that redoes the calculations for a list and replots. It's kind of slow.

Now, I'm replotting the entire thing, but it's stacking one axis on top of the other, hundreds after a few minutes of use.

```
deltaPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
c = deltaPlot.add_subplot(111)
c.set_title('Delta')
deltaDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(deltaPlot, master=master)
deltaDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,rowspan=2)
```

and the main loop runs

```
c.cla()
c.plot(timeSpread,tdeltas,'g-')
deltaDataPlot.show()
```

It's clearing the initial plot, but like I said the axes are stacking (because it's redrawing one each time, corresponding to the slightly altered data points). Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Could you add working code example? For example what is `master`?

Answer (score 1):

To improve speed there are a couple of things you could do:

**Either** Run the `remove` method on the line produced by plot:

```
# inside the loop
line, = c.plot(timeSpread,tdeltas,'g-')
deltaDataPlot.show()
...
line.remove()
```

**Or** Re-use the line, updating its coordinates appropriately:

```
# outside the loop
line, = c.plot(timeSpread,tdeltas,'g-')

# inside the loop
deltaDataPlot.show()
line.set_data(timeSpread,tdeltas)
```

The documentation of Line2d can be found [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data).

You might also like to read the [cookbook article on animation](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations).

HTH